# Arraylist not returning index correctly

Tags: java, android, arraylist, indexof

Hello i have a Arraylist of ID's to which i am searching for match index of that ID i am doing this

```
 private int getCategoryPos(List<String> list_ids, String category) {
    return list_ids.indexOf(category);
}
```

i am passing arraylist and category name to find the index i have multiple categories so i want multiple match value index so i am doing this in a loop check below

```
 for(int i=0;i<getmusicvalue.size();i++) {

            Log.i("spinposlistse", String.valueOf(getmusicvalue.get(i)));
            String replace = String.valueOf(getmusicvalue.get(i)).replace("[", "");
            String replace1 = replace.replace("]", "");

            int spinnerPosition = getCategoryPos(musiclist_ids, replace1);
           spinposlist.add(String.valueOf(spinnerPosition));

        }
```

its is returning first index properly and others are -1 which means index not found but it is present in my Arraylist below are my original list

```
[72894F9E-B925-479F-8D74-DEC36F81D2A6, 85FB184F-92E0-4816-9715-9E85218AF994, E4853E42-E721-4259-873F-1017A1CAC554, 73445B72-6E45-4D3F-91A3-DAEAD3E3E1EF, 84EFC496-691E-4F78-BF71-62148C34317E, 4AD6E3AD-5BD3-4531-B13B-F6EA17C1FD1A, D739E7BF-DBF6-47FB-90C8-68EC2711C73C, 46139642-4639-42DB-BEC2-AF7CBFA7BB83, BA895652-5D22-45EC-A1BC-BC457856C343, 74ED6675-241E-4EB2-B0A7-6CC78D3EC80D, 2FC2CE27-370D-4D27-BD0C-8FC0F6613A18]
```

Searching list is:

```
[[84EFC496-691E-4F78-BF71-62148C34317E,  85FB184F-92E0-4816-9715-9E85218AF994]]
```

You can see both ids are present in original list but it give me wrong output below is my output

```
[4, -1]
```

Anyone please help me what is wrong in my code?

Comment: try adding toString() after get(i) like get(i).toString()

Comment: and how are you creating your musiclist_ids??

Comment: what are those `replace("[", "")` / `replace("]", "")` for? is it some bad formatted JSON output?

Comment: [[84EFC496-691E-4F78-BF71-62148C34317E,  85FB184F-92E0-4816-9715-9E85218AF994]]

replace are for these two open and close brackets

Comment: so first parse your data into `String[]` or `List<String>` data type and then perform an ordinary search

Comment: @pskink musiclist_ids is already in List<String>

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try in this way ?

```
for(int i=0;i<getmusicvalue.size();i++) {
    Log.i("spinposlistse", String.valueOf(getmusicvalue.get(i)));
    String replace = String.valueOf(getmusicvalue.get(i)).replace("[", "");
    String replace1 = replace.replace("]", "");
    int spinnerPosition = getIndex(musiclist_ids, replace1);
    Log.i("Got Index", ""+spinnerPosition);
    spinposlist.add(String.valueOf(spinnerPosition));
 }
```

Add method to get actual index:

```
   private int getIndex(List<String> list, String item){
        int position = -1;
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(i))){
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return position;
    }
```

Hope this will help you.